# customise the scrollbar in Firefox and IE without know the container height

Tags: javascript, browser, scroll

I need the scrollbar in my website has the same look and feel cross browsers, I already checked couple of plugins that are used to create customised scrollbar, for example [this one](http://manos.malihu.gr/), however, it seems that all these plugins require a fixed container's height(i.e the height should be pre-defined). But in my case, pre-defined height is not an option, anyone know other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think most of custom scrollbar do not require fixed height. Look at this [comparison table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing) - row `Dynamic height`. Height is not required, but if you want to see scrollbar you should set `overflow:auto` and `height` or `max-height`, otherwise scrollbar will never be shown. Try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) - look at basic scrollbars demo page and play with 'Add/Remove content' buttons - you will see that height is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I use this one, works best for me.. Try it out.

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

and regarding fixed height/width... The scrollbars only appear if inner content's height/width exceeds the container's height/width..